# Solving system of partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving two PDEs together for two functions `y`, `G`:

```
Derivative[0,1][y][x,t] + 2 Derivative[1,0][G][x,t] == 0
Derivative[0,1][y][x,t] + Derivative[1,0][G][x,t] == 2
```

I want to solve those PDEs to find the value of both `y[x,t]` and `G[x,t]`

I tried to use `DSolve` but it doesn't work with me, even it is easy to do it by my hand. I would like to get the answer through *Mathematica*.

Comment: Hi, do you have initial conditions for the system?

Comment: Please post code in proper input form that can be pasted into *Mathematica*. You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations are so trivial they're beneath DSolve's dignity. They don't even look differential enough.

```
eqns = {D[y[x, t], t] + 2 D[G[x, t], x] == 0, D[y[x, t], t] + D[G[x, t], x] == 2};
halfsol = Reduce[eqns, {D[y[x, t], t], D[G[x, t], x]}]
sol = DSolve[halfsol, {y[x, t], G[x, t]}, {x, t}]
```

Comment: Dear aooiii, i just wanted to tell Thank you.........

Comment: You're welcome ^_^

Comment: Dear aooiii, i tried the same way to solve those group but Mathematica couldnt give ans kindly give your comments, eqns = {D[y[x, t], t] - \[Epsilon] (G[x, t] - y[x, t]) == 0, 
   D[G[x, t], t] - 1/A D[G[x, t], x, x] - B (y[x, t] - G[x, t]) == 0};
halfsol = Reduce[eqns, {D[y[x, t], t], D[G[x, t], x]}];
sol = DSolve[halfsol, {y[x, t], G[x, t]}, {x, t}]

Comment: Sorry, but my hack only worked with that particular system. Please don't take the method too seriously; it's NOT how things should be done. And I don't know how to make Mathematica solve the new one (except there must be no brackets [] around Epsilon, but that doesn't help much), so let's just consider it unsolvable by Mathematica.